# Express 4 fire event on session ended

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am setting a max age on the session cookie for an express session

```
app.use(session({ secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SECRET, key: 'sid', cookie: {secure: false, maxAge: 3000} }));
```

How can I use the event emitter, or custom events for express (which comes with an event emitter internally) - to fire an event when the session is ended and send data to the view layer?

Comment: Even if you could have some event fire when that session ended, how would you send that to the view. The view get rendered when the client makes a request. You can't push to the client without web sockets.

Comment: Thats what i'm trying to figure out, how can you display a modal or something when the session is ended? it might not be possible.

Comment: You can either use web sockets or have your client side code poll your server on some interval to check to see if the session has ended.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I get what you want to achieve, but if you want to check the session has ended, you could just set a session data

```
if (req.session.isInit !== true) {
    // The session has been reinitialized
    // do something here
    req.session.isInit = true;
}
```

Otherwise, you could easily implement your own session store which would inherit the store of your choice (by default the express memory store which also inherits EventEmitter) and override the method `#destroy` which resets the session:

```
var MemoryStore = session.MemoryStore;
var inherits = require('util').inherits;

var MyStore = function () {
    MemoryStore.call(this);
};
inherits(MyStore, MemoryStore);

MyStore.prototype.destroy = function (sid, fn) {
    this.emit('resetSession');
    MemoryStore.prototype.destroy.call(this, sid, fn);
};

var myStore = new MyStore();
myStore.on('resetSession', function () {
     // do something here
});
app.use(session({ store: new MyStore()secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SECRET, key: 'sid', cookie: {secure: false, maxAge: 3000} }));
```

Comment: right so this would still require a refresh of the browser to check the isInit variable, this is actually the solution I've had in place already, I think thats congruent across the net with apps is you refresh and a modal will pop up, or it will simply redirect to the login page again with a message saying "your session has timed out", thank you!

Comment: This requires a new request yes. If you want to check this client-side without refreshing, you could either set a cookie client-side or ask the server for the isInit value (using a websocket or polling it asynchronously)